# LARAVEL Get duplicated rows from several tables

Tags: laravel

have some problem with getting data in laravel

i have table `companies` and `addresses`, want to get all companies which have same address

an example

companies table

| id | name | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | company 1 | 30/01/2023 |
| 2 | company 2 | 30/01/2023 |
| 3 | company 3 | 30/01/2023 |
| 4 | company 4 | 30/01/2023 |

addresses table

| id | company_id | a1 | a2 | city | state |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | aa1 | aa1 | cc1 | ss1 |
| 2 | 2 | aa2 | aa2 | cc2 | ss2 |
| 3 | 3 | aa3 | aa3 | cc3 | ss3 |
| 4 | 4 | aa1 | aa1 | cc1 | ss1 |

i need companies with ids 1, 4 because they has same address

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | company 1 |
| 4 | company 4 |

Comment: can you share the query that you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What immediately comes to my head is using a SQL join to achieve this i.e using a SELF JOIN to compare the table with itself while also using subqueries to ensure the address information is available on the tables you're comparing. Please try below query out, should be of help:

```sql
SELECT t2.c2_id as id, t2.c2_name as name
FROM (
  SELECT
    c.id as c1_id, c.name as c1_name,
    CONCAT(addresses.a1, ' ', addresses.a2, ' ', addresses.city, ' ', addresses.state) as c1_address
  FROM companies c
  JOIN addresses 
    ON c.id = addresses.company_id
) t1, 
(
  SELECT
    c.id as c2_id, c.name as c2_name, 
    CONCAT(addresses.a1, ' ', addresses.a2, ' ', addresses.city, ' ', addresses.state) as c2_address
  FROM companies c
  JOIN addresses 
    ON c.id = addresses.company_id
) as t2
WHERE c1_id <> c2_id
      AND c1_address = c2_address;
```

https://sqlize.online/s/dp

Comment: and now in eloquent format ^_^